# hibernate OneToOne relation with compound key

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

[image]

```
@Embeddable
public class UserCompoundKey implements Serializable {  

    private int user_id;
    private String user_name;

    public UserCompoundKey(){

    }
    public UserCompoundKey(int userid,String username){
        this.user_id = userid;
        this.user_name= username;
    }
    public UserCompoundKey(String username){        
        this.user_name= username;
    }

    //@Column(columnDefinition="int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT")
    public int getUser_id() {
        return user_id;
    }
    public void setUser_id(int user_id) {
        this.user_id = user_id;
    }
    //@Column(nullable=false,columnDefinition="varchar(255) default 'no name'")
    public String getUser_name() {
        return user_name;
    }
    public void setUser_name(String user_name) {
        this.user_name = user_name;
    }


}
```

user class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
@IdClass(UserCompoundKey.class)
public class User {



    private int user_id;
    private String user_name;
    private String user_pass;
    private int company_id;
    private int user_type_id;
    private boolean is_expire;
    private Date last_login_date;
    private boolean login_status;
    private UserDetail userDetail;

    public User(){}
    public User(UserCompoundKey userCompoundKey){
        this.user_id = userCompoundKey.getUser_id();
        this.user_name = userCompoundKey.getUser_name();        
    }

    @Id
    @AttributeOverrides({   
    @AttributeOverride(name = "user_name",
    column = @Column(columnDefinition="varchar(255) default 'no name'")),
    @AttributeOverride(name = "user_id",
    column = @Column(columnDefinition="int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT"))
    })




    @Column(name="user_password")   
    public String getUser_pass() {
        return user_pass;
    }
    public void setUser_pass(String user_pass) {
        this.user_pass = user_pass;
    }
    public int getCompany_id() {
        return company_id;
    }
    public void setCompany_id(int company_id) {
        this.company_id = company_id;
    }
    public int getUser_type_id() {
        return user_type_id;
    }
    public void setUser_type_id(int user_type_id) {
        this.user_type_id = user_type_id;
    }
    public boolean isIs_expire() {
        return is_expire;
    }
    public void setIs_expire(boolean is_expire) {
        this.is_expire = is_expire;
    }
    public Date getLast_login_date() {
        return last_login_date;
    }
    public void setLast_login_date(Date last_login_date) {
        this.last_login_date = last_login_date;
    }
    public boolean isLogin_status() {
        return login_status;
    }
    public void setLogin_status(boolean login_status) {
        this.login_status = login_status;
    }
    public void setUserDetail(UserDetail userDetail) {
        this.userDetail = userDetail;
    }
    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_info",
    joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") },
    inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id") }
    )
    public UserDetail getUserDetail() {
        return userDetail;
    }



}
```

user detail/info

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user_info")
public class UserDetail {


    private int user_id;    
    private String first_name;
    private String last_name;
    private String email;
    private String phone_number;
    private String address_1;
    private String address_2;
    private String country;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private Date created_date;


    public void setUser_id(int user_id) {
        this.user_id = user_id;
    }
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue 
    public int getUser_id() {
        return user_id;
    }   
    public String getFirst_name() {
        return first_name;
    }
    public void setFirst_name(String first_name) {
        this.first_name = first_name;
    }
    public String getLast_name() {
        return last_name;
    }
    public void setLast_name(String last_name) {
        this.last_name = last_name;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String getPhone_number() {
        return phone_number;
    }
    public void setPhone_number(String phone_number) {
        this.phone_number = phone_number;
    }
    public String getAddress_1() {
        return address_1;
    }
    public void setAddress_1(String address_1) {
        this.address_1 = address_1;
    }
    public String getAddress_2() {
        return address_2;
    }
    public void setAddress_2(String address_2) {
        this.address_2 = address_2;
    }
    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }
    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }
    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }
    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }
    public Date getCreated_date() {
        return created_date;
    }
    public void setCreated_date(Date created_date) {
        this.created_date = created_date;
    }


}
```

showing this error

1st exception

```
 Unable to find properties (user_name, user_id) in entity annotated with @IdClass:com.wellclub.test.User
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:774)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.processArtifactsOfType(AnnotationConfiguration.java:546)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.secondPassCompile(AnnotationConfiguration.java:291)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1333)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:867)
    at com.wellclub.test.UserTest.main(UserTest.java:17)
```

2nd exception

```
A Foreign key refering com.wellclub.test.User from com.wellclub.test.User has the wrong number of column. should be 2
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.TableBinder.bindFk(TableBinder.java:273)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder.bindJoinToPersistentClass(EntityBinder.java:520)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder.createPrimaryColumnsToSecondaryTable(EntityBinder.java:510)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder.finalSecondaryTableBinding(EntityBinder.java:441)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SecondaryTableSecondPass.doSecondPass(SecondaryTableSecondPass.java:25)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.secondPassCompile(AnnotationConfiguration.java:325)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1333)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:867)
    at com.wellclub.test.UserTest.main(UserTest.java:17)
```

Comment: Please post your code including the Hibernate mappings and import statements.

Answer (score 0):

Add getter methods for `user_id` and `user_name` in your `User` class, Hibernate needs these to access them.

```
public int getUser_id() {
  return user_id;
}

public String getUser_name() {
  return user_name;
}
```

---

Further to the above:

There are several different strategies for mapping composite keys and it looks like you are mixing them.

Since you have defined a compound key class `UserCompoundKey` and marked it as `@Embeddable`,

You do not need the class annotations:

```
@IdClass(UserCompoundKey.class)

@Id
@AttributeOverrides({   
@AttributeOverride(name = "user_name",
column = @Column(columnDefinition="varchar(255) default 'no name'")),
@AttributeOverride(name = "user_id",
column = @Column(columnDefinition="int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT"))
})
```

Remove these annotations from `User`.

You also do not need the fields:

```
private int user_id;
private String user_name;
```

in `User`, as these fields are already contained within your `UserCompoundKey` class. Remove these also.

You then simply need to add a new field in 'User' to map the compound key class key that you already defined:

```
@Id
private UserCompoundKey compoundId;
```

Finally, don't forget to add a getter and setter to `User` for the new field.

Comment: Please don't edit the old exception as that no longer applies to the old code.